# Null Exception in Android AsyncTask onPostExecution

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I followed a tutorial online. However I can't get it to work and I keep getting a NullPointerException. The app spends about 2-3 minutes attempt to connect to my server and then just shuts down.

I think the problem is in Array Adapter.

The Array Adapter has 13 Objects but its show null on setting it to a spinner Please Help me sort out the issue i'm new to android so need some help.

**My code MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner SID;
    Spinner SName;
    Spinner SMailID;
    Button Btngetdata;

    ArrayList<String> Name = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> UID = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> MailID = new ArrayList<String>();

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_USER = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

    JSONArray user = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner SID = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.listID);
        Spinner SName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.listName);
        Spinner SMailID = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.listMailID);
        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btngetData);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONParse().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(json != null)
            {
                try {
                    // Getting JSON Array
                    user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
                    JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
                        UID.add(user.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_ID.toString()));
                        Name.add(user.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_NAME.toString()));
                        MailID.add(user.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_EMAIL.toString()));

                    }
                    //Set JSON Data in TextView
                    ArrayAdapter<String> IDAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, UID);
                    IDAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    SID.setAdapter(IDAdapter);

                    ArrayAdapter<String> NameSource = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Name);
                    NameSource.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    SName.setAdapter(NameSource);

                    ArrayAdapter<String> MailIDSource = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MailID);
                    MailIDSource.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    SMailID.setAdapter(MailIDSource);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this).create();

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to AndroidHive.info");

                // Setting Icon to Dialog
                alertDialog.setIcon(null);

                // Setting OK Button
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the ERROR i get**

```
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316): java.lang.NullPointerException
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at learn2crack.asynctask.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:122)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at learn2crack.asynctask.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    11-26 23:38:06.038: E/AndroidRuntime(26316):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which is line no. 122 ?

Comment: Multiple declarations for SID,SName,SMailID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already declared

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 Spinner SID;
 Spinner SName;
 Spinner SMailID;
```

So Change this

```
 Spinner SID = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.listID);
 Spinner SName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.listName);
 Spinner SMailID = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.listMailID); 
 // becomes local to onCreate.
```

to

```
 SID = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.listID);
 SName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.listName);
 SMailID = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.listMailID);
```

Comment: Thanks , din notice dat.